# Garbage value in c

Tags: c

My code is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
    int p;
    scanf("%d",p);
    printf(p*10);
}
```

But its giving garbage value,Why?

Comment: Did you enable all the warnings given by your compiler? Did you use a debugger to debug your program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just print the value of this non-initialized variable.

a scanf expects a pointer to write the answer. you provide a integer who looks like a memory address. try to compile with -Wall for example

Answer (score 6):

You need to use `&p` in the `scanf` call. You also need to use a format string in the `printf()` call.

Here's a list of the major issues your code has:

- `scanf("%d", p)` - you need to pass a pointer to an int, not an int. Right now you are writing to whatever address/value the uninitialized int variable contains.
- `printf(p*10)` - you need to pass a format string as the first argument and values according to the format string as the following arguments. In your case, `"%d"` to print an integer and then `p` (or `p*10`) as the second argument.

Here's the fixed code:

```
int main()
{
    int p;
    scanf("%d", &p);
    printf("%d\n", p*10);
}
```

Comment: what about %d in printf command

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%d",p);
printf(p*10);
```

It amazes me that this actually works !! Especially the `printf` command.

You need to read about `Format Specifiers` and `printf` And `scanf` commands in C. :)

Comment: This is the place where you'd share your answer, not your surprise.

Answer (score 0):

use `reference operator(&)` in `scanf` and `format specifier` in `printf`.

You always get a `garbage` value if you dont use `'&'` operator in your `scanf` because the entered value doesn't get stored in the `memory location` of your `variable`. It doesn't know where to get stored..

It scans your value but it wont get stored in the variable. and the reason of getting garbage value is that you are using a `local` variable and the memory location for it is `STACK`.